# Debian64 VM VBox startup error: Windows Host

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, kali-linux

I have just installed (possibly incorrectly) Virtual Box additions on my Debian64 virtual machine and when I start up that machine it gives me an error:

**[FAILED] Failed to start vboxadd-service.service.**
**See 'systemctl status vboxadd-service.service' for details**

Any advice on how to fix this will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you run `systemctl status vboxadd-service.service` like it suggested?

Comment: I have ran the command and it just gives me a sort log of actions that happen. Here is the photo: http://imgur.com/a/89PiF